# Why .NET code form app (VS2019) not works on PI board?

Tags: .net, .net-core, cross-platform, ubuntu-16.04, orange-pi

i installed SDK in Orangepi board  (ARM based)

```
tayfur@OrangePi:~$ dotnet --info
.NET Core SDK (reflecting any global.json):
 Version:   3.1.301
 Commit:    7feb845744

Runtime Environment:
 OS Name:     ubuntu
 OS Version:  16.04
 OS Platform: Linux
 RID:         ubuntu.16.04-arm
 Base Path:   /home/orangepi/dotnet/sdk/3.1.301/

Host (useful for support):
  Version: 3.1.5
  Commit:  65cd789777

.NET Core SDKs installed:
  3.1.301 [/home/orangepi/dotnet/sdk]

.NET Core runtimes installed:
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 3.1.5 [/home/orangepi/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 3.1.5 [/home/orangepi/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App]

To install additional .NET Core runtimes or SDKs:
  https://aka.ms/dotnet-download
```

after I cerate with vs2019 a app

windows Form App (.NET Core)

I addeed form and bttuon for say helllo.

I tested on pc with " dotnet test1.dll"
its work fine

But Its not work in orangepiboard (ARM ubuntu 16.4)

errror :

```
tayfur@OrangePi:~/netcore$ ls
test1.deps.json  test1.exe  test1.runtimeconfig.dev.json
test1.dll        test1.pdb  test1.runtimeconfig.json

tayfur@OrangePi:~/netcore$ dotnet test1.dll

It was not possible to find any compatible framework version
The framework 'Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App', version '3.1.0' was not found.
  - No frameworks were found.

You can resolve the problem by installing the specified framework and/or SDK.

The specified framework can be found at:
  - https://aka.ms/dotnet-core-applaunch?framework=Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App&framework_version=3.1.0&arch=arm&rid=ubuntu.16.04-arm
tayfur@OrangePi:~/netcore$
```

How can i solve it.
Basically, i want write a form application on vs2019 and it run on orangepi board.

Comment: I'm not sure that .NET Core supports windows forms on non-windows platforms; IIRC *mono* does (there's a blog post [here](http://comfilewiki.co.kr/en/doku.php?id=comfilepi:running_.net_winforms_applications_with_mono:index)) that walks you through it, but... for .NET Core (not mono), you might need a cross-platform UI toolkit,  possibly [MAUI](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/introducing-net-multi-platform-app-ui/)